# PHP: How can one fake an Interface at runtime?

Tags: php, interface, type-hinting

I am trying to implement a State-Machine design pattern in PHP.  The program makes a method invocation on a wrapper object that knows about state transitions.  The state object performs the action, but each state object has a different interface that matches the available methods of the state. This is done to encapsulate function so that the object does not need to have a method definition for every possible action that can be performed on the object through its lifetime, as this would be an unmanageable object.

```
//Psuedo-code:
class StatefulObject{
    protected $state;
    /* the dynamically set state order prevents us from having
     * to give states knowledge of eachother.
     */
    protected $dynamicallySetStateOrder;
    public function __call( $name, $arguments ){
        /*
         * we pass all method calls to the state object
         * the state object performs the action on the
         * StatefulObject
         */
        if( method_exists( $this->state, $name ) ){
             $this->state->$name( $arguments );
        }
    }
}
interface StateInterface{
    public function setStatefulObject( $obj );
    /*
     * a state does not know about states before and after, but it
     * knows if an object meets the prerequisites to enter its own
     * state
     */
    public function willAcceptStatefulObject( $obj );
}
class State1 implements StateInterface{
    public function action1( ... ){ ... }
    public function action2( ... ){ ... }
    public function action3( ... ){ ... }
    ...
    public function action99( ... ){ ... }
}
class State2 implements StateInterface{
    public function actionA( ... ){ ... }
    public function actionB( ... ){ ... }
    ...
    public function actionZ( ... ){ ... }
}
```

The problem then arrives when I try to pass a `StatefulObject` into a method that uses Type Hinting to describe an object that is in a particlar state.  For example, if I wish to have a method `someMethod( State2 $obj )`, I want to be able to pass in the `StatefulObject` without having to give the `StatefulObject` a definition for every method handled within all the object states that it can hold.

The `StatefulObject` implements the interface of the object contained within it, but PHP would not see this and would throw an Exception if the `StatefulObject` currently holding a `State2` object were to be passed into `someMethod`.  How can I dynamically provide an interface illusion to the system components?

Comment: You should be able to type hint the interface. If that isn't working for whatever reason, you could always implement your own type check logic at the start of `__call()`

Comment: could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appears to be in changing the design pattern.  Instead of storing the state in the StatefulObject, I now wrap the StatefulObject in the state and use type hinting based on the state and not on the StatefulObject.

My current system now has a hybrid approach to the State Design Pattern, when the interface stays the same, but the behavior changes, I pass the StatefulObject and it calls the state's method to perform the action.  When the interface needs to be different, I pass the state instead.  The state refers to the object, and the object refers back to the state.

[image]

Methods that require methods provided by State1 receive a State1 object, which carries with it the object inside.  Methods that require a more generic interface are passed the StatefulObject, and the StatefulObject carries with it the state.  As it passes through the system, it is almost like a Mobius: its inside becomes its outside again and again to meet the purpose of the moment.